# youtube stops playing when switching chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

When playing some youtube video in a frame/embedded (from an external site, not directly on youtube.com), playing pauses when I switch to another tab (make the playing tab inactive).

Is there any way to turn this off?
So that when I switch to some other tab, video will keep playing in it.

A good example is playing some track on https://www.shazam.com/myshazam

P.S  This behavior is shared between various browsers - checked and replicated on Chrome & IE.

Comment: Tried turning off javascript?

Comment: @Xen2050 Turning off JS globally?! How can you browse the web in 2017 with JS turned off?! That's definitely not an option.

Comment: As a test at least, if it works then you can investigate further. Keeping javascript off at least with NoScript would be a lot safer too, but an infection & identity theft could be fun & exciting if you're into that sort of thing (I'm not)

Comment: None of these work in 2022

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to go in chrome://flags (in the address bar) and change **pause-background-tabs** to **disabled**. I think it is working for me.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist anymore. 
I set #disable-background-video-track and #stop-in-background to 'disabled' but the problem persists.

Comment: btw. my workaround is to use Firefox for non-stop Youtube playback.

Comment: Neither of those exist in 80.0.3987.149. Any update in 2020?

Comment: @x0a disabling #enable-audio-focus-enforcement works for me as grokster said

Answer (score 4):

In 86.0.4240.75, disabling chrome://flags/#calculate-native-win-occlusion worked for me on Windows

Comment: That was my issue exactly. I noticed it had to do with having another window over it, so the native occlusion thing does make sense.

Comment: This was it for me. Happened when I switched windows or new tabs.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, F%$* Google btw

Answer (score 3):

On Google Chrome Version 71.x

Disable [expensive-background-timer-throttling](http://chrome://flags/#expensive-background-timer-throttling)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please improve your post by explaining how this will solve the problem and provide a bit more detail on what to actually do.

Comment: This flag worked for me. To clarify, it is a flag on the `chrome://flags` called `expensive-background-timer-throttling` and I set it to "disabled."

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it with this flag:
chrome://flags/#enable-audio-focus-enforcement

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a music enhancer (extention) in your browser it might also be affecting it. That was basically my case as it overwrites the flags.